# Align the navbar-brand to left of page

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-4

How do I align the navbar-brand to the left of the page? I would like my Website Name to be in the same line with the menu list.

This is my current menu bar:
[Current Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV2tw.png)

Notice, in my Current Navigation Bar, my Website Name is above the menu list.

Here is my code saved at Bootply.com:
https://www.bootply.com/ksxCEDHXPo

Many thanks.

Comment: it [looks on the left](https://jsfiddle.net/p0jvre10/) to me

Comment: Without seeing the menu, I can't see what's wrong here. Place your code in https://www.bootply.com/ and you'll see what we mean.

Comment: Please add you CSS so we can see the styling.

Comment: Without a complete example of your markup, it's impossible to help: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I wanted my menu to look like this:

[Click here for my expected navigation menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCqQ9.png)

I needed to put the column span to the navbar-brand and navbar-collapse parameter. 
This was my code before:
    Website Name

```
    </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
```

Here is my code for the update:

> ```
>     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
>
>     <div class="container-fluid">
>
>     <div class="navbar-header">
>
>       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
>
>         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>         <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
>       </button>
>
>       <a class="navbar-brand col-md-4" href="#">Awesome Theme</a>
>
>     </div> <!-- nav-header -->
>     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-md-8" id="myNavbar">    
>
>       <?php 
>             wp_nav_menu(array(
>                 'theme_location'=>'primary',
>                 'container' => false,
>                 'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
>             )
>         );
>       ?>
>
>   </div><!-- collapse -->
> </div><!--  container-fluid  -->
> </nav>
> ```

For more information on columns check out the site below:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp